# Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, google-colaboratory

This is probably a very easy answer, but I am still new to Python. I am trying to use a dataset to output a DataFrame, but after I create the
DataFrame, it is only outputting numbers, not strings.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


players = np.genfromtxt("LINK_THAT_MY_DATA_IS_COMING_FROM.csv", delimiter=",", names=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(players)
df
```

The DataFrame only outputs numbers, am I completely missing something simple, or is there a specific function I need to use to output strings and ints to a DataFrame.

Comment: did the solution helped?

Answer (score 0):

try
[pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv)

```
players = pd.read_csv(LINK_THAT_MY_DATA_IS_COMING_FROM.csv", delimiter=",", names=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(players)
df
```